# Parse REST API makes two entries in DB

Tags: php, ios, rest, parse-platform

I have an iOS app which calls a PHP file to send out email invitation and makes an entry into Parse DB. The email is only sent once, but it makes two DB entry of same records. I am unable to identify whats going wrong, kindly help.

The PHP REST code which makes the DB entry

```
$objectData = '{"fromID":"'.$email.'", "fromName":"'.$name.'", "toName":"'.$friendName.'", "toEmailID":"'.$friendEmail.'"}';  
$rest = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$objectData);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$response = curl_exec($rest); 

$obj = json_decode($response);
$objectId=$obj->objectId;
if($objectId){ <email sending code goes here> }
```

The code from my XCode project, which calls this PHP file.

```
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.com/some.php?var1=%@&var2=%@&var3=%@&val4=%@",val1,val2,val3,val4];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; 
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Kindly help, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What about the code that creates the entry in Parse? That's key to finding the issue.

Comment: Hi Niraj, the parse DB entry is made via the PHP code above ($response = curl_exec($rest); ) this is the actual code that inserts, bu the rest object is associated to the object in the lines above.

Comment: Have you tried using the official PHP SDK instead of making your own cURL calls?